# QML Code Coverage Analysis

Tags: qml, qt-quick

Are there any tools for performing code coverage analysis on QML code? Is such a question even applicable to a declarative language like QML?

Comment: Its really interesting question. First what came to my head is "Tools -> QML/JS -> Run Checks" in QtCreator.

Comment: It's really interesting, indeed. The coverage should involve any js function as well as bindings, property assignments, and so on. I guess it's not so easy to do on QML, for some features are directly accessible by instrumenting the QML files, while some others require to instrument the C++ code (as an example - unless you don't care about if and when a dynamic binding happens, but you are interested on the code executed by that function). The same happens if you have classes written in C++ and exported to the QML environment, of course.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/mutaphysis/qml-tools) or perhaps in future [this](http://blog.froglogic.com/2014/10/measuring-qml-coverage/)?

Comment: The first one doesn't cover the C++ code, anyway. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hm. Since QML is declarative with som js on top, and since declarative probably won't need any coverage test, maybe a tool that separates out js and does coverage on that would do?

Answer (score 4):

There was a talk recently on QtCon about C++ and QML code coverage. https://conf.qtcon.org/en/qtcon/public/events/407 (Open the page and click on video link to watch)

The talk was by Harri Porten who is co-founder and co-CEO of froglogic GmbH, a company which sells automated GUI testing tools. They also have a blog post about QML code coverage
http://blog.froglogic.com/2014/10/measuring-qml-coverage/

Answer (score 0):

Classic coverage treatment of JavaScript and C++ does not have to be the end of QML coverage analysis.

For example, coverage of [States](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-state.html) is thinkable as well. Are all of them entered during test execution? That's what users
of [Coco](https://www.froglogic.com/news/froglogic-releases-code-coverage-tool-qt-quick-qml-applications/) filed as feature requests at least.