# How to identify unused code & files in QML

Tags: qt, qml, static-analysis, dead-code

Need to identify dead code and unused files in the codebase for QML & JS files. Are there any tools for Qt/C++?

Answer (score 2):

Good question. Will monitor it, because Qt/QML world lacks of such OpenSource tool. Somehow it is related to [QML Code Coverage Analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684010/qml-code-coverage-analysis).

Still there is no straight answer. Here are few possible solutions I've found so far.

- Since you are talking about JS, there is [ESLint](https://eslint.org) and here is WIP project [eslint-plugin-qml](https://github.com/oltodo/eslint-plugin-qml), Lint JavaScript code in QML files.
- There is proprietary paid tool [froglogic Coco Code Coverage](https://www.froglogic.com/coco/) that looks like can parse QML too. Can't say something since never tried, but it looks promoting.